# Runtime switch between << and >> in C++

Tags: c++, stream

in C++ if you have a streamable class like the ios streams, an `fstream` or a `stringstream` or any other streamable type, you have a function that streams something, you want the ability to decide, at runtime, what is the direction of your stream: how you can do that ?

For example I'm writing a simple parser for a binary-based file format, and I would like to use the definitions for both the input ( when reading of the file ) and the output ( when writing the file ).

Comment: boost serialization may be a good model.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: @TomKerr you are thinking about a method in particular or what else ... ?

Comment: @TomKerr I mean what is the big advantage, I can define the file structure with that ? I get a different streamable type ? What helps me to abstract ?

Comment: Your binary format is a series of fields that you visit, yea?  That lib visits both ser/unser with the same code path, which has the advantages you describe.

Comment: @user2485710 - as long as the method signature is the same, you can use a function pointer and just change the method it points to during the runtime and call through the function pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fstream takes a flag saying if its an input or output stream (`ios::in`/`ios::out`), just use that instead of ifstream/ofstream. Same holds true for stringstreams (that tends to be less interesting).